# Maps aren't baking the way I need it to

Tags: texture-baking, baking, shader-nodes, pbr

I'm trying to bake a diffuse map, but the parts where it's supposed to be metal-ish, turns black. Does anyone know why this happens? Maybe other maps are affecting it?

[image: This is what I want it to look like in the shader editor]
[image: the parts that are needed to be grey, turn black]
[image: this is what the diffuse map looks like]

Comment: Hello, when does it turn black? Maybe pack your image and share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: My file is a little too large for pasteall, but here's a google drive link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nRKFJU8gRBhW_5U26KSJaLRZrCGqWfYf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: your node setup seems complicated but from what I see you just need to tweak the ColorRamp needles in order to make the material more glossy

Comment: That is not happening to me ... when original material is pluged to output and diffuse image texture node is selected it seems to be working for me https://imgur.com/5fCsP5P

Comment: @moonboots tweak the needles where? sorry about the node setup, it's very messy/unorganized, this is my first time trying node texturing

Comment: Maybe try to adjust texture's brightness/contrast.

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth I'm trying, but I can't seem to get it. Were you able to get it correctly?

Comment: @Wallon: No as I didn't have this kind of problem and it is but a suggestion (that's why it is a comment). You could also try some PBR 2 or 4K metal texture if you don't find a procedural one.

Comment: @Lukasz-40sth I was able to fix it. I simply disconnected any connected nodes accept for Color textures, leaving the plain colors on the mesh, and then baked again. I figured that maybe the normals/roughness/metallic textures were somehow affecting it?

Comment: @Wallon: glad you solved the problem, happy for you. I don't bake textures so I can't tell.